# Will my YT & Cloud Account be migrated after upgrading to Google Workspace?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration, cloud, google-workspace

thank you for your interest in helping with my question,
Currently, I have a normal google account with the brand name of my company ( Gmail + Youtube + Google Sites ) this same account is used in the google cloud platform & I had set up a billing account when asked for (currently GCP is in the trial but I intend to be using paid services when the trial ends) .
I was wondering if I get a google workspace subscription will this account be transferred ( Youtube + Gmail + sites + cloud) to the newly Workspace account or not?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only the management of your account formerly Gmail to Google Workspace will be migrated.

The rest, you will have to manually migrate over to your new Google Workspace account.

You will need these for migrations:

1. [Email](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6178640)
2. [Sites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3R6R.png), you will need to copy the file from your Gmail account to your GW one and map it to your domain
3. [YouTube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3056283)

Also, If you are using a consumer Google account with a domain email address I would recommend creating the Google Workspace with a different email address from the same domain and then use the [transfer tool](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6178640) to send a request to manage all the consumer accounts needed. Here is the list of restrictions:
[image]

You need to make sure that the users accept the transfer as well, otherwise the accounts will not be migrated and they will have to rename the account to a gmail.com.

Be aware that this transfer tool only works for domain accounts

If you do decide to move forward with this, you can contact [Google Workspace Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) for guidance.

Comment: thank you for helping with clarifying this question, I think now I can do further research & proceed with the linking of all my Google services.